# Request a page with server code

Tags: asp.net

I need to request a series  of pages and want to do from the server code  as if you were doing with  Ajax, I can do?, thanks

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question and http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `WebClient` class.

Comment: +1. Just to be helpful: `var pageContents = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://example.com");`

Comment: +1 just because you were able to pull some sense from that.  Are you working on that Jeopardy bot for IBM?

Answer (score 0):

Use this c# function. Add **using System.Net;** top of your page.

```
private string MakeWebRequest(string url) {
    string retValue = String.Empty;
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        request.Method = "GET";

        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader stReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        retValue = stReader.ReadToEnd();

        stReader.Close();
        response.Close();

        stReader.Dispose();
        stReader = null;
        response = null;
        request = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { 

    }


    return retValue;
}
```